# how to select elements with more attributes?

Tags: jquery

How can you select elements with more attributes?

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]')
```

This will select all checkboxes, but how can you specify one more attribute in the selector?

```
<input type="checkbox" data-test="1" />
```

How can you select all checkboxes with the `data-test` attribute set too?

Comment: Btw, if you want to select all checkboxes which have a `data-test` attribute (regardless of value), use this: `$('input[type="checkbox"][data-test]')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain them like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][data-test="1"]')
```

Answer (score 4):

Just write them one after another:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][data-test="1"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery supports [multiple attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/). So you could have something like so:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][data-test="1"]')
```

Or you could shorten it some with the [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector.

```
$(':checkbox[data-test="1"]')
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/NYX9p/